# How to do a search between a range offsets in a Binary file?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to search between a range of offsets in a binary file. I have loaded the bin file as a byte array[] and then encoded its content as String, which later I use to do a search of String sequence. The thing is I need to do that search but only in a range of offset I input (start and ending)... and also do the search but with differents String sequences, so the printing gives me something like this:

```
0x180 30
0x240 17
0x350 30
0x464 30
0x650 17
```

Right now I'm getting all the sequences with 30 by themselves.

This is my code:

```
byte[] model = Read.readBytesFromFile();

String x = HexBin.encode(model);
String v30 = "05805A6C";
String v17 = "0580336C";

String beg = txtBeg.getText().toString();
int beg2 = Integer.parseInt(beg);
int start = (model.length + beg2) - model.length;

String end = txtEnd.getText().toString();
int end2 = Integer.parseInt(end);
int ending = (model.length + end2) - model.length;

int index = 0;

if (x.contains(v30)
{

    if (cbxVer.isSelected()) {
        while ((index = x.indexOf(v30, index)) != -1) {
            System.out.println("0x" + (Integer.toHexString((index / 2) + 4)) + " 30");
            index = index + 2;
        }

    }
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Wrong File");
}
```

Comment: you already got that question posted; are you getting anything right out of this? are you getting anything wrong?  or you just want us to fill in your answer??

Comment: @gpasch My previous post was about how to do the search. Now I'm trying to do the search between a range. I have tried for loops with no results other than repeating several times the same search (x.contains). Also, I need to do the same search but with another String sequence.

Comment: `(a + b) - a` is `b`. Searching for a string in a string of hexadecimals can return a result that’s 4 bits off. Also, converting a byte[] into a String should only done with great care. All in all, if you have a byte[] in which you are looking for another byte[], write code that deals with byte[].